# Complex Integration for $\int te^{\alpha t}\cos(\beta t)dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How can I solve the general integral
$$\int te^{\alpha t}\cos(\beta t)dt$$ using complex integration? Usually we split the integral into real and imaginary parts, but I don't know how we can do that with this. Maybe we can apply Euler's Formula, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^x te^{zt}dt = \frac{1}{z^2}\big(zxe^{zx}-(e^{zx}-1)\big)$$
where $z$ is a complex number, using integration by part.

To apply this result, just set $z=\alpha+i\beta$ and take its real part, which is the integral you desire.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Integrating by parts, gives
$$
\int t e^{a t}\,dt=\frac 1a\left(t-\frac1a\right)e^{a t}+\textrm{constant}, \quad a \neq 0 \tag1
$$ Then you may just write
$$
\int te^{\alpha t}\cos(\beta t)dt=\frac12\int te^{\alpha t}e^{i\beta t}dt+\frac12\int te^{\alpha t}e^{-i\beta t}dt=\frac12\int te^{(\alpha +i\beta) t}dt+\frac12\int te^{(\alpha -i\beta) t}dt
$$ and use $(1)$ with appropriate conditions on $\alpha,\beta$.